# Are cremated ashes medically harmful to the living?

Tags: risks, inhalation, cadavears

Disneyland's Haunted Mansion and Pirates of the Caribbean have become notorious public touristy locations to sprinkle/spread ashes of deceased loved ones, according many articles, including this one: [Secrets of Disneyland](http://www.cnn.com/2011/LIVING/07/01/ten.secrets.disney.mf/). Disneyland has a firm "no spreading cremated remains" policy, and it always removes the ashes from the rides ASAP upon discovering that they have been covertly sprinkled by park guests on the ride.

I understand completely why Disneyland does this... Cultural sensitives, ash buildup can cause maintenance issues, cleanliness standard, among tons of other things (but out of respect for everyone else), but **I'm curious if cremated ashes of a cadaver are medically harmful or cause any health hazards to living humans? Like is it toxic to accidentally inhale a bit of it?**

**Is Disneyland also removing the ashes immediately because of health risks??** Or is more of the cultural-respect and clean atmosphere (and probably legal standards)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Ash weight and composition**
>
> Cremated remains are mostly dry calcium phosphates with some minor minerals, such as salts of sodium and potassium. Sulfur and most carbon are driven off as oxidized gases during the process, although a relatively small amount of carbon may remain as carbonate.

And all metals implants, fillings etc are removed before the ashes are presented to the relatives.  Joint prosthetics are sold for scrap metal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremation

So, there's nothing there harmful to the living.